# Can git apply leave conflict markers inline like git rebase?

Tags: git, conflict, rebase, apply

git rebase leaves the conflict markers inline in files; something like:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
Whatever line + context is different from the previous commit
=======
Whatever line + context is different from the commit being applied
>>>>>>> new version, new branch:app/views/common/version.txt
```

When I use git apply to apply a patch created with git format-patch, it will fail to leave any files modified by default. I can give it --reject which will cause it to create .rej files for those that have unresolvable conflicts, but really, I want it to modify files and leave every in the state that git rebase does so I can just open the file, manually merge it, and then git add it and tell git apply to continue.  Is there some way to do this that I just don't know of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me the following works:

```
git init
seq 1 30 > file
git add file
git commit -m 1-30
sed -i '13a13.4' file
git commit -m 'add 13.4' file
git format-patch -1
git reset --hard HEAD^
sed -i 13d file
git commit -m 'remove 13' file
git am -3 0001-add-13.4.patch
```

After that `file` has conflict markers. That is use `git am -3` instead of `git apply`.

Comment: Hmmm - interesting that does indeed seem to do what I'm wanting. I thought that git am used git apply - perhaps it's uses an internal API that isn't accessible through git apply's command line options. Thanks!

Comment: TL;DR: use the `-3` option to `git am` or `git apply` *(whichever you happen to use)*. The option tells git to perform a merge instead of just aborting on conflict.

Answer (score 8):

Use the option with three way merge:

```
git apply -3 0001-patch.patch
```

Comment: That does not work:
error: patch failed: file.cpp:383
error: repository lacks the necessary blob to fall back on 3-way merge.
error: file.cpp: patch does not apply

Answer (score 8):

A different solution is to apply the patch using `patch --merge` instead of any git tool. This worked much better for me when bringing some changes from a completely different git repo, so for which I couldn't (easily) use `git am -3` or `git apply -3`.

Comment: It can even do: patch --merge=diff3

Comment: This resolves " That does not work: error: patch failed: file.cpp:383 error: repository lacks the necessary blob to fall back on 3-way merge. error: file.cpp: patch does not apply "

Comment: +1 for teaching me about `--merge`, which was just what I was looking for. More details: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html (or just `man patch` if you have a Linux/GNU environment nearby. Unsure if `--merge` is part of POSIX or not.)